# How to pass cell array from MATLAB to .NET method

Tags: .net, matlab, cell-array

I am new to MATLAB. By using the command `NET.addAssembly` I am loading a .NET assembly, instantiating an object of assembly's class, then I am invoking the methods of the class.

Passing parameters such as `double`, `char` to method of assembly class is working fine.

But when I am trying to pass cell array to method of instantiated class, it shows an error parameter mismatch.

I have done the following procedure:

```
s = NET.addAssembly('name of assembly')
t = s.AssemblyHandle.GetType('Class present in assembly');
obj = System.Activator.CreateInstance(t);
obj.PassCellArray(CellArray);
```

.NET Method

```
public void PassCellArray(System.Object[] dd) {}
```

According to the documentation, we can pass the cell array to a method which has parameter as `System.Object[]`.

So please help me for how to pass cell array to .NET method.

Answer (score 2):

What exactly is stored inside this cell-array?

According to [the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/handling-net-data-in-matlab_bte9oxc-1.html), elements of a cell can be any of the following supported types:

- Any non-sparse, non-complex built-in numeric type shown in the [Primitive Type Conversion Table](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/handling-net-data-in-matlab_bte9oxc-1.html#bte9o7y-1)
- char
- logical
- cell array
- .NET object

While you cannot pass the following MATLAB types to .NET methods:

- Structure arrays
- Sparse arrays
- Complex numbers